# How to get this output?

Tags: python

I am learning python. I have this question related to list in python. How to solve this query?

I have tried using for loops and using double operators but they did not work.

```
lst = ['mango', 'apple', 'beans', 'garlic']
lst1 = ['mango', 'apple']
```

i want this output

```
lst2 = ['beans', 'garlic']
```

Comment: lst2 = [x for x in lst if x not in lst1]

Comment: set(lst).difference(lst1)

Comment: @kiner_shah difference() accepts any iterable

Comment: @jandob, got it! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
a = [i for i in lst if i not in lst1]
```

Output:

```
['beans', 'garlic']
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the order of the final results, you can use set subtraction

```
>>> set(lst) - set(lst1)
{'garlic', 'beans'}
>>>
```

Comment: how can it will solve using two for loops and without converting in set

Answer (score 0):

Use a set to take the difference then convert back to list.

`list(set(lst) - set(lst1))`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using XOR operator:

```
set(lst) ^ set(lst1)
```